# Issue loading external swf on main file with as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loading, external

Hi I'm new to Flash CS6 and and AS3 and I have been stuck on this iPad/Android restaurant menu I have been doing. I amm trying to load an external swf on my main swf but have been getting this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at cuisine/init()[C:\Users\PAO\Desktop\OZ\SWIPE\cuisine.as:32]
    at cuisine()[C:\Users\PAO\Desktop\OZ\SWIPE\cuisine.as:22]
```

I got the code of the swipes from a tutorial I found online. in the different sections fo the menu I was planning to load different swfs because I couldn't get the code to work for all the sections at the same time.

like I said, I am new to as3 and I really don't understand all the coding so i'm really stuck at a dead end.

hoping a kind soul could help me get out of this rut. the files can be found [here](http://www.ce-studios.com/files/SWIPE.rar)

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bit unintuitive to load external SWFs, especially if you are new to AS3. If I remember correctly, a big problem can be that you need to wait for the ENTIRE swf to load before trying to access anything.

You should only try to access code from the external swf after the Event.COMPLETE event. see [here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3loader/) for more info

I would also suggest use the [Greensock](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) loader instead since it's a bit simpler.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've decided to try to fix the script so it's all in 1 .as file as opposed to loading an external swf although im getting a different problem. could anyone help me on how i can fix this code?   private function init():void
  {
   Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
   this.stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, handleSwipe,);
   
  }
  
  private function init():void
  {
   Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
   this.stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, handleSwipe2,);
   
  }

Comment: This basically defines two eventListeners (this is a new concept in AS3 which is VERY important to understand try this tutorial for some help http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3events/) These listeners will fire when you swipe the screen.